# Grep: How to exclude lines before/after if a line contains an unwanted string?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I'm running a command with `diff` on 2 very big assembly dumps. I see lots of output like this:

```
903c903
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
995c995
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
1123c1123
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
1191c1191
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
1278c1278
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
1347c1347
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
1546c1546
<        inc      dword ptr [ebp-10H]
---
>        add      dword ptr [ebp-10H], 1
1552c1552
<        inc      esi
---
>        add      esi, 1
```

I don't really want to see the lines that contain "Pentium 4" or "generic X86 CPU"; specifically, if there is a line that contains "Pentium 4" I want to exclude that line and the 3 lines above it.

Is it possible to do this using `grep`? I know about `grep -v 'Pentium 4'`, but that only works for single lines. I can't do `grep -v -- '---'` obviously, since there are some valid diffs that contain a triple-dash.

If the grep query were run on the above code, the result should be

```
1546c1546
<        inc      dword ptr [ebp-10H]
---
>        add      dword ptr [ebp-10H], 1
1552c1552
<        inc      esi
---
>        add      esi, 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like process substitution here. Let's assume **file_a** is:

```
; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU                                                                                                                                                          
inc      dword ptr [ebp-10H]
```

And **file_b** is:

```
; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
add      dword ptr [ebp-10H], 1
```

Running

```
diff -I "^;" file_a file_b
```

will return:

```
1,2c1,2
< ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for generic X86 CPU
< inc      dword ptr [ebp-10H]
---
> ; Emitting BLENDED_CODE for Pentium 4
> add      dword ptr [ebp-10H], 1
```

Which isn't exactly that you want I guess. However, when you try with process substitution i.e.

```
diff <(grep -v '^;' file_a) <(grep -v '^;' file_b)
```

you will get:

```
1c1
< inc      dword ptr [ebp-10H]
---
> add      dword ptr [ebp-10H], 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-I` option of `diff` to exclude lines which match a certain pattern from the diff:

```
diff -I 'Pentium 4\|generic X86 CPU' file1 file2
```

The pattern must be matched by both lines, that's why you need to use the `|` (logical *or*) operator to make the pattern match the original and the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use process substitution in `bash` to strip out the comments from the source files:

```
diff <(grep -v '^;' file1.s) <(grep -v '^;' file2.s)
```

Comment: Good catch that the lines are actually comments! But I don't see the advantage over `diff -I'^;' file1 file2` here.

Comment: @hek2mgl nevermind - fat fingers hit enter before I finished typing... I was going to suggest the `diff -I'^;' ...` bit, but I see you beat me to it... And, yes, in this particular case, the `diff -I` route is obviously more efficient, and it is sufficient for the stated case. There may be more complex situations, however, where it's not as easy to specify an ignore pattern, so I suggested the process substitution recipe as an alternative tool...

Comment: :) The day I've learned about `diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)` changed my life! (really)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{r=r $0 ORS} (NR%4)==0{if (!/Pentium 4/) printf "%s", r; r=""}' file
1546c1546
<        inc      dword ptr [ebp-10H]
---
>        add      dword ptr [ebp-10H], 1
1552c1552
<        inc      esi
---
>        add      esi, 1
```

Comment: This answer has been flagged as low quality. If it answers the question, consider adding a bit of text to explain how it works.

Comment: No, that's completely unnecessary. You're supposed to **review** flagged answers not rubber-stamp the tool flagging it. Do not reply to this so you don't waste any more of our time.

Comment: Even if the answer is technically correct, it would be nice to add a few explanation, don't you think Ed?

Comment: Absolutely not. If the user doesn't understand this then there's a lot more of the absolutely basic awk syntax/usage they also don't understand so they'd be far better off looking this up in a man page or, god forbid, a book than being spoon fed just this one standalone application which they'd then try to apply to completely inappropriate problems since it's all they know how to do. I really don't want to get into this discussion again.